Meaning of "on the dreary littorals of Alexandria, with her sex broken" in Durrell's Justine
I'm unable to figure out the meaning of this sentence in Lawrence Durrell's Justine:

I found Melissa, washed up like a half-drowned bird, on the dreary littorals of Alexandria, with her sex broken....
Durrell, Lawrence. Justine. 1957, rev. 1962. The Alexandra Quartet pp. 13–203. With a new introduction by Jan Morris. London: Faber and Faber, 2012. p. 26, ellipses in original.

I understand neither the claim that the narrator found Melissa on the littorals, nor the adverbial clause.
With regard to the first, the sentence is without specific context. It appears to refer to the general circumstances of their meeting rather than to any particular occasion when the narrator comes across Melissa on the beach. Melissa is a prostitute, and the narrator first encounters her when his temporary roommate Pursewarden has hired her for an evening party. Another guest has slipped her a dose of Spanish Fly to which she has had a severe reaction. Under the mistaken impression that the narrator is a doctor, Pursewarden implores him to attend to Melissa. So I don't understand how the narrator can say that he found her "on the dreary littorals"; they are not by the seashore.
With regard to the second, I cannot fathom "with her sex broken." What does "her sex" refer to? I thought of three possibilities, but none seems likely:

Does the narrator believe womanhood in general was broken around the time that he met Melissa? He does have a tendency to make sweeping misogynist statements (e.g., "Women are sexual robbers," p. 160), but in that case I don't see the connection between the two parts of the sentence.
If "her sex" means merely her genitals, I again don't understand how a vulva, vagina, or clitoris can be said to be "broken." Is the narrator referring to the allegedly aphrodisiac effects of Spanish Fly, which due to Melissa's allergic reaction can be said to have "broken" rather than enhanced her sex drive?
Melissa is ill throughout the novel and eventually dies of an unnamed disease, perhaps syphilis. Is broken sex a hint that Melissa is syphilitic? The child she bears during the novel's action appears to be healthy enough, so I thought perhaps Melissa was not syphilitic; and indeed, cursory googling suggests that she is tubercular, which was my initial guess. But even if she is syphilitic, "her sex was broken" seems like an odd way to allude to that.

Is any of these alternatives the intended meaning? If so, how? If not, what does the sentence mean?

Alexandria is on the water, the littorals could be the shoreline made up of rocks, not necessarily a beach at all. For me, sex broken means broken as a woman but it's perhaps not definitive in any way.
